# How to remove dotted line in visual studio that appears around word word that is being edited?

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I am trying to edit, lets say a property, a dotted line appears around word being edited in Visual Studio. I have tried to play with different settings in Tools>Environment>Fonts and Colors, but I still can't remove it. Does anyone know how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [Plain Rename](https://vlasovstudio.com/plain-rename/) extension to remove the dotted line.

Comment: Excellent! It was driving me nuts! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove those gray dots, as it indicates that visual studio has a suggestion to make your code simpler.

Comment: Hmm, do you know how to change appearance of this line?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I don't think this is actually possible ;(